# Push to repository button is disabled in AWS glue job for Jupyter Notebook job even after configuring Git in Version Control

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I have configured my Jupyter Notebook job in aws glue etl with Git PAT and repo names, but the Push to repository button is still disabled. I have another visual ETL job for which button is enabled. I have tried Jupyter with Glue 3 & 4 version same issue with both. Any solution for this issue?

[image: Below is the disabled button]

Comment: Are you having the same issue if you use CodeCommit? I'm seeing the same thing in AWS GovCloud. It might be worth sending feedback to AWS because this is some really janky behavior.

Comment: I tried deleting the repo and recreating it in case there was some issue with the commit hash and manual changes to the branch. Same issue.

Comment: Have you checked the iam_roles? Are they sufficient? Refer here:[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/edit-job-add-source-control-integration.html]

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to the official AWS Support Team raising this issue as I faced it as well. It is indeed an error on their end and yet to be resolved as of November 2023.
Following is the response I received from them:

> The options(“push to repository” and “pull from repository”) have been greyed out [disabled] for the Glue notebooks, due to an internal unexpected issue and service team at Amazon Web Services is working on fixing the same.

> I sincerely apologize on the behalf of AWS for the inconvenience this might have caused you. Since product roadmaps are not shared with AWS Technical Support, I do not have an ETA or a time frame on when this behaviour would be fixed. However, I would recommend monitoring the below links for any announcements related to AWS Big Data. [What's new with AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/new/)

While the issue is being handled at their end, you can follow this **Temporary work-around**:

As I checked other ETL Job types i.e. Glue Spark/Python Shell, `Push` and `Pull` buttons are active there.
Those can be used to access your preferred repository [GitHub, CodeCommit, etc.].

***Keep working in your Jupyter Notebook as you were before, at the end copy-paste your scripts to the mentioned glue jobs and push that to your repository.***

Hope this helps!